# Apache TransportException when running cassandra and netflix.astyanax library without any specific error message

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, astyanax

I am trying to execute a query on Cassandra.
port used is 9160.
Thrift server is running. by using the following command.
./nodetool enablethrift
using Cassandra 3.0.9

````
Caused by: ! com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TransportException: TransportException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=23(23), attempts=1]org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
! at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:197)
! at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:65)
! at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:28)
! at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$ThriftConnection.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:151)
! at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:69)
! at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:256)
! at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractThriftCqlQuery$3.execute(AbstractThriftCqlQuery.java:80)
! at lithium.cassandra.dao.AbstractCassandraDao.executeQuery(AbstractCassandraDao.java:84)
!... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: ! org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
! at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
! at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
! at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
! at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
! at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
! at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
! at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
! at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
! at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
! at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1689)
! at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1674)
! at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftCql3Query.execute_prepared_cql_query(ThriftCql3Query.java:29)
! at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractThriftCqlQuery$3$1.internalExecute(AbstractThriftCqlQuery.java:92)
! at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractThriftCqlQuery$3$1.internalExecute(AbstractThriftCqlQuery.java:82)
! at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
!... 66 common frames omitted```
````

Comment: one question - do you really need to use Thrift? It's basically dead for a long time

Comment: Yes, It is part of the really old and huge project. Can not change it.

Comment: Sorry, but you're not going to find much help for a deprecated driver which uses a deprecated protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue because I had a few threads but the data I had to process was huge with each request. (200000 objects needed to be processed as part of one request. and each object was being queued up.) Once I reduced the number of objects received, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on how you solved the issue? What exactly did you change and how. Hopefully your answer will be helpful to others with similar issues.